# With CodedUI, is there a way to determine that an element with a given ID exists on a webpage?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

For example, if my page contains the following code:

```
<a id="foo" href="#">Click Me!</a>
```

Is there a way with CodedUI to verify that a link with id equal to "foo" is present on the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the link with the Coded IU cross-hairs (ie assertion building) tool. The properties shown should include the `Id` field. You can then generate an assertion that the link contains the text `Click Me!`. Make sure the generated search properties include the required value for the link property. If the `Id` field or the displayed text are variable (perhaps their values are data driven or found earlier in the test) then before finding the control (implicitly or explicitly) set the required values. This should work because the assertion can only be checked if the required field is found on the screen and that find uses teh `Id` field.

Perhaps your question is a more general "is there such a link anywhere on the web page"? If so then you can use the `GetChilden()` to do a recursive traverse of the web page. Check each UI Control found to see if it has the desired values.